# Extplorer File Manager Not Working

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

On my localhost, I have extfilemanager its a file manager that combines php, js and ajax to make a file manager, I have it working well locally (using xampp PHP Version 5.3.1) but I have moved it to a windows-shared hosting godaddy server and all of a sudden it doesn't work.

The server is running PHP Version 5.2.14, which is different from the XAMPP PHP installation but that shouldn't affect it right?

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Unable to load Ext, core YUI utilities (yahoo, dom, event) not found.
```

I've moved exactly the same directory over using Coda first, and then deleted it and tried FileZilla just to make sure the files were getting sent over properly. I've noticed that it uses a script called FetchScript.php to include the files that it needs.

I've had issues with "including" files using PHP on windows servers before and also "file_get_contents," this had something to do with the server not allowing absolute URLs to be included.

Has anybody come across this issue before? Thanks!

UPDATE: I went to the line which this error is thrown and it looks like this:

```
if(typeof YAHOO=="undefined"){throw"Unable to load Ext, core YUI utilities (yahoo, dom, event) not found.";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added in the yahoo-min.js and the error went away, I guess the way fetch-script.php worked didn't get along well with a windows-godaddy server, I added this into the index.php of the file manager:

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: since is in localhost, why u need to script src to outside world? a local copy will download much faster

Comment: This copy is on a godaddy server, I know it's best practice to do so. I just wanted to make sure it worked, :)